# Every bounded sequence is Cauchy?

Tags: sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I know that every [Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence) is bounded, but is the reverse true?

Comment: Whether every bounded sequence has Cauchy subsequence is a bit more interesting question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No. Consider the sequence $$1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,\dots$$
Clearly this seqeunce is bounded but it is not Cauchy. You can show this directly from the definition of Cauchy.

Alternatively, every Cauchy sequence (in $\mathbb{R}$) is convergent. Clearly the above sequence is not, thus it is not Cauchy.