# Does every bounded sequence have a Cauchy sub-sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

In [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2030157/161559) to an [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2030154/161559) it was explained why a bounded sequence is not guaranteed to be a [Cauchy sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_sequence).

But does every bounded sequence have a Cauchy sub-sequence?

I know that from any bounded sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ it is possible to pick an infinite sequence of the elements which will form a Cauchy sequence. Does this hold in other topologies as well?

The proof I know for the case of $\mathbb{R}^n$ relies on using the ordering of $\mathbb{R}$ to find a Cauchy sub-sequence for one co-ordinate at a time. But the same proof could not be applied to a topology with no ordering.

Comment: You need some form of uniform structure to define Cauchy sequence. Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556150/metric-space-is-totally-bounded-iff-every-sequence-has-cauchy-subsequence

Comment: @HenryW. That does indeed sound related. But I don't think it answers my question. Also I added metric-spaces tag to my question, because I wrote the question assuming a metric space, and I am not even sure my question would make sense in topologies which are not metric spaces.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You are right. There was one sentence in the middle of my question where I had accidentally swapped bounded and Cauchy. I have fixed that now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, it is not true in general that every bounded sequence has a Cauchy subsequence. Define a metric $d$ on $\Bbb R$ by $d(x,y)=\min\{|x-y|,1\}$, and consider the sequence $\sigma=\langle n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$. Clearly $d(m,n)=1$ whenever $m,n\in\Bbb N$ and $m\ne n$, so $\sigma$ has no Cauchy subsequence, even though $\Bbb R$ itself is bounded in the metric $d$. (Note that $d$ generates the usual topology on $\Bbb R$.)

Comment: But "totally bounded" will do the trick, right?

Comment: @bof: Total boundedness even ensures that every sequence *is* bounded, so it ensures that *every* sequence has a Cauchy subsequence.

Comment: I meant, if the *sequence* is "totally bounded" then it has a Cauchy subsequence, but maybe that's not standard terminology.

Comment: @bof: Ah, okay. No, I don’t think that I’ve seen *totally bounded* applied to anything but a space, though one certainly could extend the term to apply to a sequence whose range was totally bounded as a subspace of the metric space in question.

Answer (score 5):

This happens for a metric space precisely when *bounded* is the same as *totally bounded*.

A subset $A$ of a metric space $X,d$ is

1. *bounded* if $\sup\{d(x,y):x,y\in A\}<\infty$
2. *totally bounded* if, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exist $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\in A$ such that $A\subseteq\bigcup_{i=1}^n B_d(x_i,\varepsilon)$

where $B_d(x,r)=\{y\in X:d(x,y)<r\}$.

It is clear that any totally bounded subset is bounded, but the converse is not true; for instance, for any metric $d$ we can define a metric $d'$ inducing the same topology as $d$ where every subset is bounded, namely
$$
d'(x,y)=\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}
$$
Now just take a metric space which is not totally bounded (for instance, complete but not compact) and you have an example of a bounded set which is not totally bounded.

Now suppose that every bounded set in $X,d$ is totally bounded. If a sequence is bounded, the set of its points is totally bounded, so it is precompact and its closure in the completion $\hat{X},\hat{d}$ is compact. A sequence in a compact metric space always has a convergent subsequence. (The result can also be proved without mentioning completions.)

Also the converse is true. If every bounded sequence has a Cauchy subsequence, then every bounded set is totally bounded.

Indeed, suppose $A\ne\emptyset$ is bounded, but not totally bounded. Then there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that no finite set of balls of radius $\varepsilon$ centered on points of $A$ covers $A$. In particular, chosen arbitrarily $x_0\in A$, there are points of $A$ outside of $B_d(x_0,\varepsilon)$. Suppose we have chosen $x_0,\dots,x_{n-1}$. Then we can also choose $x_n\in A$ such that
$$
x_n\notin\bigcup_{i=0}^{n-1}B_d(x_i,\varepsilon)
$$
Thus we have a sequence $(x_n)$ such that, for $m\ne n$, $d(x_m,x_n)\ge\varepsilon$. Such a sequence can have no Cauchy subsequence.

The standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the property that every bounded subset is totally bounded.

The Heine-Borel theorem can be generalized to all complete metric spaces: a subset of a complete metric space is compact if and only if it is closed and totally bounded.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about boundness of a sequence, so I'm assuming we are talking about a metric space.

In a metric space, every Cauchy sequence is bounded.

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subset X$ be a Cauchy sequence in a metric space, i.e., for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is a positive integer $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n, m \geq n_0$
$$ d(x_n,x_m) < \epsilon. $$

Take $\epsilon = 1$ and let $n_0$ be such integer. Then

$$ d(0,x_n) \leq d(0,x_{n_0})+d(x_{n_0},x_n) < d(0,x_{n_0}) + 1, \; \forall n \geq n_0. $$

Now let $$\delta = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n_0} \{d(0,x_i),d(0,x_{n_0})+1\}$$ and we conclude that $d(0,x_n) \leq \delta$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, so $(x_n) \subset B(0,\delta)$.

Comment: That's not answering the question, is it?

Comment: He changed the question after my answer. Not my fault.

Comment: There was a typo in one sentence of the question where bounded and Cauchy had been swapped. But in the title and twice in the paragraphs expressing the question in more detail the order of the implication was in the intentional order all along.

Comment: I answered the question written. When I saw that you had swapped it, Brian had already replied. The only one seeing a problem here is Clement, since your doubt is solved.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple counterexample would be to consider the discrete topology on an infinite set, say $\mathbb N$ and consider a sequence of distinct elements, like $1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

(Note that the only convergent sequences in a discrete topology are the eventually constant ones, and the above sequence can't have such subsequences.)